# Format ambiguous "XM.D.20" to as.Date with R

Tags: r, date

I have

```
days<-c("X1.22.20", "X1.23.20", "X1.24.20", "X1.25.20", "X1.26.20", 
"X1.27.20", "X1.28.20", "X1.29.20", "X1.30.20", "X1.31.20", "X2.1.20", 
"X2.2.20", "X2.3.20", "X2.4.20", "X2.5.20", "X2.6.20", "X2.7.20", 
"X2.8.20", "X2.9.20", "X2.10.20", "X2.11.20", "X2.12.20", "X2.13.20", 
"X2.14.20", "X2.15.20", "X2.16.20", "X2.17.20", "X2.18.20", "X2.19.20", 
"X2.20.20", "X2.21.20", "X2.22.20", "X2.23.20", "X2.24.20", "X2.25.20", 
"X2.26.20", "X2.27.20", "X2.28.20", "X2.29.20", "X3.1.20", "X3.2.20", 
"X3.3.20", "X3.4.20", "X3.5.20", "X3.6.20", "X3.7.20", "X3.8.20", 
"X3.9.20", "X3.10.20", "X3.11.20", "X3.12.20", "X3.13.20", "X3.14.20", 
"X3.15.20", "X3.16.20", "X3.17.20", "X3.18.20", "X3.19.20")
```

I want these days (row names of https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series) formatted as.Date.

However I have the following problem: 1. The leading X, 2. There is no leading zero in days 3. There is no leading zero in months 3. Year is abbreviated as 20.

I havent found a way to tackle all these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the "X"s with `gsub`:

```
days <- gsub("X", "", days)
```

Then, assuming that the first number is the month, the second the day and the third the year, recode with the `as.Date`function:

```
days <- as.Date(days, "%m.%d.%y")
```